# Aside armed clashes in the West Bank, is there another reason why people in the Gaza strip are more likely to support a two-state solution?

Tags: israel, palestine

> Unlike previous surveys, support for the general two-state solution
> among Palestinians is higher in the Gaza Strip than in the West Bank,
> 40% and 28% respectively (though support has generally been higher in
> Gaza for the detailed package). Indeed, the decline in support for the
> two-state solution occurred entirely in the West Bank strengthening
> the speculation that the drop was triggered by the great rise in armed
> clashes between Palestinians and Israelis. Support for the two state
> solution remains higher among Fatah voters and those who define
> themselves as “not religious” or “somewhat religious.

https://www.pcpsr.org/sites/default/files/Summary%20Report_%20English_Joint%20Poll%2024%20Jan%202023.pdf

Aside armed clashes in the West Bank, is there another reason why people in the Gaza strip are more likely to support a two-state solution? This article mentions that the people in the Gaza strip are more likely to support a two state solution that the people in the West Bank and it provides a possible explanation by saying that the drop was likely triggered by a rise in armed clashes between Israelis and Palestinians in the West Bank.

Comment: The difference is not that large. There is a footnote mentioning a total sample size of 1270 respondents for a margin of error of +/- 3% but that's across the West bank, East Jerusalem, and Gaza. I didn't see an exact breakdown and didn't take the time to figure out the details but the margin of error on each subsample would be larger (possibly 5 or 6%). The margin of error of the difference is not exactly the sum of both but it could be quite large compared to the size of the difference itself.

Comment: In other words, it's entirely possibly the actual difference is as low as 3 to 5 percentage points and there is really nothing to explain. (On the other hand, it's of course entirely possible that it's larger than it seems). It's not uncommon to do this kind of subgroup analyses in opinion polls with 1 or 2000 respondents but there is a reason some research surveys have much larger sample sizes.